# Project management software with member rate

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I tried out some project management systems like Open Project, TeamWork, etc. But I couldn't find some features, that I need. Some requirements:

1. System should be online.
2. Budget up to 50 $ per month.
3. Set rate for hourly pay for each member or role.
4. Tracking time for each member.
5. Calculating total report, considering in calculations hourly salary and amount of closed tickets (by hours) of each member.

For example in a *Total month* report should be:

Billy Bonce 56 h closed 8 $/h rate total salary = 448$

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations. Your question still lacks some essential details, like for which operating system(s) is the software required to run, and what budget are you willing to spend? Please read [this FAQ on what is required for a question to contain enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834)

Answer (score 2):

I understand that your "members" are a kind of freelancers that are working for you and that you want to pay per hour and provide them with a bonus based on the number of closed tickets, is that right?

Time sheet tracking system don't usually include such a type of provider management, particularly not the cheap ones. ERP systems (OpenBravo, Microsoft Navision, ...) may do, but that's probably overkill, and these systems don't know anything about tickets.

So your cheapest option is to use a standard time tracker and to export the time sheet and ticket data to an Excel sheet or a shared database where you calculate the amount per "member" once a month.

[www.project-open.com](http://www.project-open.com) (disclaimer: I'm part of the team) does includes a ticket tracker, time sheet and provider management. However, you would need a customization in order to automatically calculate the "Billy Bonce" 448$ type of financial documents.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/project-management/) would fit your requirements. You are able to define individual hourly rates for each team member, track their work hours and get calculations of totals in the timesheet report.

You can group the report by users, tags, etc.

[image]